# Плагин для Brackets

Tags: редактор, adobe-brackets

Как называется плагин для Brackets, который автоматически сортирует CSS-код в алфавитном порядке??

Comment: Вот здесь еще можно почитать подробнее http://habrahabr.ru/post/230589/

Comment: Brackets – плагины, настройки, горячие клавиши. Напомню, что скачать редактор можно бесплатно. Пользоваться им вы сможете только в Гугл Хром. Установив приложение, вы получаете при внесении изменений колов: отображение кириллического текста, подсветку синтаксиса, подсказки при редактировании HTML, http://bracketspro.ru/besplatnyjj-redaktor-brackets-plaginy-i-nastrojjki-2/JS, CSS-файлов.

Comment: Была дана ссылка на несуществующую страницу. Требуется исправить ответ.

Comment: Данный ответ не содержит ответа на поставленный автором вопрос. Он о другом. Спасибо.

Comment: Очень удачно я нашел. Подробная статья о самых популярных плагинах для Brackets
Рекомендую к прочтению: https://use-web.ru/news.php?id=26&tid=3

Answer (score 1):

Если ничего не путаю, brackets CSSComb, ссылка на расширение с сайта [CssComb](http://csscomb.com) https://github.com/i-akhmadullin/brackets-csscomb